# GitHub - how to submit individual pull request in case of multiple commits

Tags: github

I've made multiple commits to my local repository and now I intend to do pull request to submit these changes over to the source/master.

When I do a pull request, it automatically includes all of my commits. I couldn't locate a way to submit each commit in its own pull request. Could someone please give some pointer on how to do this on GitHub.

**Update**
To clarify on this question, I forked a new local repo from upstream/master. Then, in my noobie-ness, I made new files in my local master itself without branching repo out first. So, effectively, my question is with these changes committed to local master repo, is there a way to raise pull requests for each new file one by one, and not for all of them in one go.

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I'm not sure if there is a better way in GitHub, but in general, you can create a new branch for each pull request, cherry-picking the commits you want for each request.
The new branches should preferably be based on upstream master to make the merge painless.

Using command line git, using `origin` as your own github remote repo, `upstream` is the upstream remote:

```
git checkout -b {my_pull_request_feature_branch} upstream/master
git cherry-pick {sha1_of_first_commit_for_feature_X} [sha1_of_another_commit_for_feature_X] ...
git push origin {my_pull_request_feature_branch}
```

Repeat for each pull request.

When you do a pull request on GitHub you can then choose which branch you want to send in your request.

Comment: Thanks. It is more clear now. So, if I understand correctly, I start with forking the 'upstream' master. With this, I get my own local copy to work with. After this, I make a new branch with - git checkout -b branch1 - and create new file / do some work in there. Once finished, I should start a pull request - git push upstream branch1.....In my case, what I have done is - being a complete noobie, I forked the upstream, & added new files to the master directly, without making any branches.. Now the master has new files and if I make a new branch. it will also have these new files. What to do.?

Comment: The solution to the problem that the master has new files is to base your feature branches off of upstream/master instead of your own master. If you follow my suggestion above you will have a feature branch that only contains the changes you want to send upstream. When you are ready to send your pull request you push your feature branch to origin/branch1, not upstream.

Comment: This works, but I had to run `git remote update` after adding the upstream remote so that git would know about `upstream/master`.

Answer (score 6):

A commit does not stand on its own, it always links to the full previous history. So if you ask to pull commit B which depends on your commit A, then you are also asking to pull A, because your work in B depends on it.

If you want to submit multiple independent pull requests, you should make sure that those commits are completely independent of each other. So they should be on their own branches. This also makes it easier for the project maintainers to integrate your pull request, as they can just merge the branch without having to cherry-pick stuff.

Comment: Thanks @poke. The new files I added are independent of each other.

Comment: The files might be, but the commits are not. Commits contain snapshots of the whole working directory not just single files or even diffs.

Comment: yup got it. I had just started with git & forked new repo. No changes other than adding these new files. Thanks.